# Trying to evaluate a limit of a sum of cosines and am stuck on something that looks like a Riemann sum,

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, riemann-sum

here's where I am stuck:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \cos(kx/n)\frac{1}{n}$$

so...it *looks* like at this point I could convert to a Riemann integral, but to which one?

Maybe $$\int_0^{\infty} \cos(t) dt?$$

That wouldn't converge, so it wouldn't be good.

How could I proceed?  It's easy to accept that $\large \frac{1}{n}$ maps to $dt$, when going from a Riemann sum to a Riemann integral, but I particularly have trouble figuring out how to convert the discrete variable to the continuous, integration variable, t.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: The limit is $1/x \cdot \int_0^x \cos(t)dt $

Comment: The limit corresponds to the integral $\int_0^1 \cos(tx)\, dt$.

Comment: @levap I doubt it since for $x=0$ it's the harmonic series, which diverges.

Comment: You are right about the Riemann sum. If instead of $1/n$ it was $x/n$ you have $\int_0^x \cos(t)dt $. Multiply and divide by x and the limit is the integral in the my last comment. Of course if x is zero the limit doesn't work out.

Comment: @GregoryGrant For $x = 0$, the sum is identically one (note that the summation is over $k$, not $n$).

Comment: Hi @Joel, my answer agrees with yours:  $\large \frac{sin(x)}{x}$.  Thanks so much for your comment.  I feel a bit better now with converting the discrete variable into the continuous variable :-)

Comment: Thanks so much for your comments, @levap :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: How would you write $$\int_0^1 \cos(xt) \,dt$$ as a Riemann sum?

Comment: Hmmm @Snow, something like $\sum_1^{N} cos ( ?) \frac{1}{N}$ , so that the *total* interval length is 1.  What do you think?  I am confused about the input for cosine, though.  Would it just be... $xn$?  Seems like such an...arbitrary choice...and that I'm not following any hard rules to make that conversion.  (the only rule I am aware of in such conversions is that mesh(p) must go to zero, which we clearly have from 1/n...) Thanks,

Comment: @user301446, Almost. You have $\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \cos(x t_k) \frac{1}{N}$. The first time most students encounter Riemann sums, they see it not in the generality of partitions and mesh, but with equally sized subintervals. Can you write an expression for $t_k$ if you want subintervals to be of equal length and $t_k$ is the left end point of the $k$-th subinterval?

Comment: Hi @Snow ooh...hmm...$\frac {k}{N}$?  so that $\frac{k}{N}$ belongs in the k-th sub-interval where it is to be the input of cosine - to give the height of the rectangle...I think...

Comment: ....so that...letting mesh(p) go to zero, such an input becomes the continuous variable, $t$.  so, it's the mapping $\frac{k}{N} \to t$, so that in total the mapping is from $\frac{k}{N}x \to tx$

Comment: What do you think @Snow?  :-)

Comment: ...which means the limit is $\large \frac{sin(x)}{x}$ ... @Snow ...

Comment: Thanks for leading me to the right answer :-)  Very exciting :-)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I would avoid using the word "mapping" here, because that can mean a function, which this is not. In this case $\frac{k}{N}$ simply corresponds to $t$. More precisely it is a "distinguished point" in a [tagged partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Partitions_of_an_interval).

Comment: Ok got it -- thanks so much, @Snow,

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $f(t) = \cos(tx)$ on $[0,1]$. Let

$$ 0 = t_0 < t_1 = \frac{1}{n} < t_2 = \frac{2}{n} < \ldots < t_{n-1} = \frac{n-1}{n} < t_n = 1$$ be a partition of $[0,1]$ into $n$ sub-intervals of length $\frac{1}{n}$. In the interval $[t_i, t_{i+1}]$ choose the point $\xi_i = t_i$. Then the Riemann sum corresponding to the partition $\{t_i\}_{i=0}^{n-1}$ and the choice of points $\{\xi_i\}_{i=0}^{n-1}$ is

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(\xi_k) (t_{k+1} - t_k) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f \left( \frac{k}{n} \right) \frac{1}{n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \cos \left( \frac{k}{n} x \right) \frac{1}{n}. $$

Hence, the limit of the expression (as $n \to \infty$) converges to

$$ \int_{0}^1 \cos(tx) \, dt = \begin{cases} [\frac{\sin(tx)}{x}]^{t = 1}_{t=0} & x \neq 0, \\ 1 & x = 0. \end{cases} = \begin{cases} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} & x \neq 0, \\ 1 & x = 0. \end{cases} $$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @levap :-)